# "Could not decode image: 'primary.png'" when installing chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I recently built a chrome extension, and uploaded it as a google store item. However, when I try to install the extension from it's store page, I get the error "Could not decode image: 'primary.png'". "primary.png" is the extension icon, as listed in the manifest.json file, and it packed within the zip file I uploaded.

Strangely I can use the extension just when testing from the extension management page. I just get that error when trying to install it from the google store. I can confirm that the primary.png file is a perfectly good png file.

I've already done some research but haven't been able to find a solution to, or even the cause of, my problem.
Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome or the web store. Try using a different program to produce the icon.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Should I try importing it into a different software and then re-exporting it? Also, would I need to wait the entire week for them to approve it all over again, or can I just change the icon?

Comment: Also, would you recommend a certain software? I used Inkscape to create the original. I really don't want to have to wait another week multiple times.

Comment: Did you find a fix for it? @KDJ

Comment: No, I don't believe I ever figured out why this was happening. I think I just republished the extension without changing anything, and that fixed it. I suspect it was some bug on Google's end.